# How to put nth row from SQL table into new table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a problem, I have created some table in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE customers (ID not null,
name varchar (20),
salary int,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Now i want to put all salaries from SQL into table from PL/SQL script, but i want to put it row by row and i have no idea how to do that i wanted to throw something in for loop, is it possible?

i wanted to do it for example in that way:

```
DECLARE
 type salaries is table of integers;
 tab salaries:= salaries();
BEGIN
 for i in 1.. (here for example numbers of IDs)
/* and here make just tab(i):= customers(i).salary; 
I know that it looks like in C++ or so but i don't know how to 
implement it in sql.*/
```

Comment: Where do you want to put those salaries ? Why row by row ?

Comment: i wanted to put into some "type tab is table of integer" table, i want to have index value (it will be like ID), and salary for a variable.

Comment: What is the purpose of the new table ? (the one which contains only the salaries)

Comment: So the question is how to populate a collection in PL/SQL using values from a database table?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
begin
for x in (select * from customers)
loop
  if x.id > 30 or upper(x.name) like '%BOSS%' then
     insert into custom_table (column1, column2, column3, column4)
         values x.id, upper(x.name), x.salary, x.salary * 1.2;
  end if;
end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this
[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TZtt.png)